# Alternative to Privacy Badger for Seamonkey?

Tags: web-browser, privacy

[EFF's Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) is a handy add-on for Firefox that safeguards your privacy by blocking third party trackers. Unfortunately, it is also incompatible with the latest [SeaMonkey](https://www.seamonkey-project.org/).

Do you know of any alternative one can install on SeaMonkey (on a Windows PC, to be more clear)?

Answer (score -1):

I use a combination of [uBlock](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/) and [uMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/) both of which work across Firefox (and therefore, Seamonkey) versions.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting uBlock, but uMatrix works only on Firefox on Android.  Also note that **an add-on for Firefox is not necessarily compatible with SeaMonkey** -- if this was the case, I'd have installed Privacy Badger itself!

Comment: is this only about android?

Comment: Yes, uMatrix is an add-on for Firefox on Android only: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/umatrix/ .  AFAIK there aren't versions for other web browsers or desktop OSes.

Comment: uBlock (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/addon/ublock/?src=search) is guaranteed to work only up to SM 2.37 which is two years old.

Comment: okay - oops, sorry. :)